# nopcommerce trying to add custom tab in admin panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, model-view-controller, nopcommerce

Ok so for the category edit page I have added a custom tab in the nopcommerce admin panel, so I'm trying to do the same for the manufacturer edit page but the content of the tab is not appearing.

[admin image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wn81.png)

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using Nop.Services.Events;
using Nop.Web.Framework.Events;

namespace Nop.Plugin.Widgets.Modifications.Events
{
/// <summary>
/// This class is used to detect when a Manufacturer is being edited in order to add a new tab for attachments.
/// </summary>
public class ManufacturerTabConsumer : IConsumer<AdminTabStripCreated>
{
    public void HandleEvent(AdminTabStripCreated eventMessage)
    {
        if (eventMessage.TabStripName == "manufacturer-edit")
        {
            //Manufacturer Attachments tab
            var manufacturerId = eventMessage.Helper.ViewContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["Id"];

            var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(eventMessage.Helper.ViewContext.RequestContext)
                .RouteUrl("Nop.Plugin.Widgets.Modifications.Admin.ManufacturerAttachments",
                    new RouteValueDictionary { { "manufacturerId", manufacturerId } });

            eventMessage.BlocksToRender.Add(new MvcHtmlString("<script>" +
                                                              "$(document).ready(function() {" +
                                                              "var tabStrip = $('#manufacturer-edit').data('kendoTabStrip').append({" +
                                                              "text: 'Attachments'," +
                                                              "animation: { open: { effects: 'fadeIn'} }," +
                                                              "contentUrl: '" + urlHelper + "'" +
                                                              "});" +
                                                              "});" +
                                                              "</script>" +
                                                              "<style>.k-link {font-weight: bold;}</style>"));
        }
    }
}
```

}

When I set a break point and get to this bit of code it tells me var urlHelper is null, though I'm not sure why.

```
var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(eventMessage.Helper.ViewContext.RequestContext)
                .RouteUrl("Nop.Plugin.Widgets.Modifications.Admin.ManufacturerAttachments",
                    new RouteValueDictionary { { "manufacturerId", manufacturerId } });
```

Anyone know why that might be null?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Omg of course right as I post my question I see the problem, I forgot to change the code from the route I copied. Sometimes copy and paste is my worst enemy.

Had to change categoryId to manufacturerId like this:

```
routes.MapLocalizedRoute("Nop.Plugin.Widgets.Modifications.Admin.ManufacturerAttachments", "Plugins/Admin/ManufacturerAttachments/{manufacturerId}",
            new { controller = "ModificationsWidget", action = "ManufacturerAttachmentsAdmin" },
            new { categoryId = @"\d+" },
            new[] { "Nop.Plugin.Widgets.ModificationsWidget.Controllers" });
        route9.DataTokens.Add("area", "admin");
```

This `new { categoryId = @"\d+" },` to this `new { manufacturerId = @"\d+" },`

Sorry folks, don't know how I missed that :(